# Django media play not able to play video in middle or chosen time

Tags: django, html5-video

I am playing a video using django media get but the problem is that if I try to start watching video in
middle, the video start at beginning.

MODEL.PY:

```
uploaded_video = models.FileField()
```

VIEW.PY:

```
def myvideo(request, video_id):
    video_get = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
    context = {'video': video_get}
    return render(request, 'video.html', context)
```

VIDEO.HTML

```
<video>
<source src="{{ video.uploaded_video.url }}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

What advices will help me to allow play it on an duration/time of video I want?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue when I server videos during development. And I think this is related to Django's runserver. Because after I change the server to Apache, this issue did not occur anymore.